# Vim different colorchemes for different file, but same backgroung color

Tags: colorscheme, filetype

I'd like to have a colorscheme but keeping my terminal color as a background color. This code achieved that

```
colorscheme MyFavoriteOne
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

I'd also like to have a different colorscheme for different filetype. By itself, this also works :

```
autocmd Filetype txt colorscheme NiceTheme
```

The problem is that now for `.txt` files my background is not my terminal background no more (even if permute the code lines above). Is there a solution?

Comment: See `:h autocmd-nested`

Comment: Also note that colorscheme is global, so if you open a txt and then a different file, it will still keep using `NiceTheme` and not go back to the other default theme. It's not really possible to have actual colorschemes per file, since you can be editing two different file types in split windows and you can't have a different colorscheme for each of them...

Comment: Yes you are right. Still not perfect, but to get closer to what I want to achieve to would be better :
```autocmd BufEnter *.txt ++nested colorscheme NiceTheme```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `FileType` autocommand to

```
autocmd Filetype txt ++nested colorscheme NiceTheme
```

to allow for nesting (by default, they do not nest).

See `:h autocmd-nested` (and thanks to Matt for the tip).